# Need to Implement Multiple Selection in Exported Excel Using ClosedXML.Excel in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

Having an export option. I am exporting all the database data to excel. The excel would have `8 master columns`. Among these 8 columns, `2 columns` would have comma separated values. For other 6 columns I have generated `dropdown` in exported excel. But for 2 columns I have to generate `multiple selection option`. I have tried manually to check the multiple option and found as `ListBox` as **ActiveX** control. Till now everything has been done using `ClosedXML.Excel` library. But how should I implement it programmatically?

```cs
DataSet ds; DataTable dt, masterDT;
string kaiproduct = ((hdfkaiproduct.Value == "" || hdfkaiproduct.Value == null) ? "" : hdfkaiproduct.Value),
       status = ((hdfstatus.Value == "" || hdfstatus.Value == null) ? "" : hdfstatus.Value),
       phase = ((hdfphase.Value == "" || hdfphase.Value == null) ? "" : hdfphase.Value),
       productlife = ((hdfproductlife.Value == "" || hdfproductlife.Value == null) ? "" : hdfproductlife.Value),
       kaibu = ((hdfwrefbu.Value == "" || hdfwrefbu.Value == null) ? "" : hdfwrefbu.Value),
       serviceline = ((hdfkaiserviceline.Value == "" || hdfkaiserviceline.Value == null) ? "" : hdfkaiserviceline.Value),
       technology = ((hdftechnology.Value == "" || hdftechnology.Value == null) ? "" : hdftechnology.Value);

ds = BLL.General.BindGridSummaryMethod("12", kaiproduct, status, phase, productlife, kaibu, serviceline, technology);
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    //dt.Columns.Remove("ID");
    //dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        /************** STATUS MASTER LIST ***************/
        // create a Status Master worksheet
        var wsStatusMaster = wb.Worksheets.Add("StatusMaster");

        // convert list item to datatable
        masterDT = BLL.MasterCommon.ToDataTable(BLL.MasterCommon.BindGrid("6"));

        // set the header row
        var headerRowStatusMaster = wsStatusMaster.Row(1);
        for (int col = 1; col <= masterDT.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            if (masterDT.Columns[col - 1].ToString() == "iValue")
                headerRowStatusMaster.Cell(col).Value = "Status";
            else
                headerRowStatusMaster.Cell(col).Value = masterDT.Columns[col - 1].ToString();
        }

        // Set Data in worksheet
        wsStatusMaster.Cell(2, 1).InsertData(masterDT.AsEnumerable());

        //Set the last row
        var lastRowSM = wsStatusMaster.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();
        /***************** END HERE ********************/

        /************* PHASE MASTER LIST ***************/
        masterDT = null;
        // create a Status Master worksheet
        var wsPhaseMaster = wb.Worksheets.Add("PhaseMaster");

        // convert list item to datatable
        masterDT = BLL.MasterCommon.ToDataTable(BLL.MasterCommon.BindGrid("4"));

        // set the header row
        var headerRowPhaseMaster = wsPhaseMaster.Row(1);
        for (int col = 1; col <= masterDT.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            if (masterDT.Columns[col - 1].ToString() == "iValue")
                headerRowPhaseMaster.Cell(col).Value = "Phase";
            else
                headerRowPhaseMaster.Cell(col).Value = masterDT.Columns[col - 1].ToString();
        }

        // Set Data in worksheet
        wsPhaseMaster.Cell(2, 1).InsertData(masterDT.AsEnumerable());

        //Set the last row
        var lastRowPhaseMaster = wsPhaseMaster.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();
        /***************** END HERE ********************/

        /************* PRODUCT LIFE MASTER LIST ***************/
        masterDT = null;
        // create a Status Master worksheet
        var wsProductLifeMaster = wb.Worksheets.Add("ProductLifeMaster");

        // convert list item to datatable
        masterDT = BLL.MasterCommon.ToDataTable(BLL.MasterCommon.BindGrid("5"));

        // set the header row
        var headerRowProductLifeMaster = wsProductLifeMaster.Row(1);
        for (int col = 1; col <= masterDT.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            if (masterDT.Columns[col - 1].ToString() == "iValue")
                headerRowProductLifeMaster.Cell(col).Value = "ProductLife";
            else
                headerRowProductLifeMaster.Cell(col).Value = masterDT.Columns[col - 1].ToString();
        }

        // Set Data in worksheet
        wsProductLifeMaster.Cell(2, 1).InsertData(masterDT.AsEnumerable());

        //Set the last row
        var lastRowProductLifeMaster = wsProductLifeMaster.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();
        /***************** END HERE ********************/

        /************* WREF BU MASTER LIST ***************/
        masterDT = null;
        // create a Status Master worksheet
        var wsWREFBUMaster = wb.Worksheets.Add("WREF BU Master");

        // convert list item to datatable
        masterDT = BLL.MasterCommon.ToDataTable(BLL.MasterCommon.BindGrid("3"));

        // set the header row
        var headerwsWREFBUMaster = wsWREFBUMaster.Row(1);
        for (int col = 1; col <= masterDT.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            if (masterDT.Columns[col - 1].ToString() == "iValue")
                headerwsWREFBUMaster.Cell(col).Value = "WREF BU";
            else
                headerwsWREFBUMaster.Cell(col).Value = masterDT.Columns[col - 1].ToString();
        }

        // Set Data in worksheet
        wsWREFBUMaster.Cell(2, 1).InsertData(masterDT.AsEnumerable());

        //Set the last row
        var lastRowWREFBUMaster = wsWREFBUMaster.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();
        /***************** END HERE ********************/

        /************* KAI Service Line Master ***************/
        masterDT = null;
        // create a Status Master worksheet
        var wsKAIServiceLineMaster = wb.Worksheets.Add("KAI Service Line");

        // convert list item to datatable
        masterDT = BLL.MasterCommon.ToDataTable(BLL.MasterCommon.BindGrid("7"));

        // set the header row
        var headerwsKSLMaster = wsKAIServiceLineMaster.Row(1);
        for (int col = 1; col <= masterDT.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            if (masterDT.Columns[col - 1].ToString() == "iValue")
                headerwsKSLMaster.Cell(col).Value = "KAIServiceLine";
            else
                headerwsKSLMaster.Cell(col).Value = masterDT.Columns[col - 1].ToString();
        }

        // Set Data in worksheet
        wsKAIServiceLineMaster.Cell(2, 1).InsertData(masterDT.AsEnumerable());

        //Set the last row
        var lastRowKSL = wsKAIServiceLineMaster.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();
        /***************** END HERE ********************/


        // create a new main worksheet
        var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("My Worksheet");

        // add a blank row before the header
        ws.Row(1).InsertRowsAbove(4);

        // set the header row
        var headerRow = ws.Row(5);
        for (int col = 1; col <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            headerRow.Cell(col).Value = ds.Tables[0].Columns[col - 1].ToString();
        }
        headerRow.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        headerRow.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0x4A4A4A);
        headerRow.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.White;

        // set the data                    
        ws.Cell(6, 1).InsertData(dt.AsEnumerable());

        // set the AutoFilter with formula in header row
        var firstDataRow = ws.FirstRowUsed().RowBelow();
        var lastDataRow = ws.LastRowUsed();
        var range = ws.Range(firstDataRow.FirstCell(), lastDataRow.LastCell());
        var headersRange = ws.Range(headerRow.FirstCell(), headerRow.LastCell());
        headersRange.SetAutoFilter();
        range.SortColumns.Add(1, XLSortOrder.Ascending); // sorting by column 1
        range.Sort();

        /* Implementing Formula */
        //var rows = ws.RangeUsed().RowsUsed().Skip(2);
        var lastRow = ws.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();

        /* Development Cost */
        var formulaRangeDevelopmentCost = ws.Range("S6:S" + lastRow); // Set the formula range first cell to the last cell
        formulaRangeDevelopmentCost.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC[-2]*F2,\"\")"; //$" =IFERROR(O" + (Convert.ToInt32(lastDataRow) - 2) + "*" + hfInternalrate.Value + ",\"\")"; // Set the formula for the range

        /* Maintenance Cost */
        var formulaRangeMaintenanceCost = ws.Range("T6:T" + lastRow); // Set the formula range from first cell to the last cell
        formulaRangeMaintenanceCost.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC[-2]*F2*5,\"\")"; //$" =IFERROR(O" + (Convert.ToInt32(lastDataRow) - 2) + "*" + hfInternalrate.Value + ",\"\")"; // Set the formula for the range

        /* soft Value */
        var formulaRangeSoftValue = ws.Range("AA6:AA" + lastRow); // Set the formula range from first cell to the last cell
        formulaRangeSoftValue.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC[-5]*F3*5,\"\")"; //$" =IFERROR(O" + (Convert.ToInt32(lastDataRow) - 2) + "*" + hfInternalrate.Value + ",\"\")"; // Set the formula for the range

        /* Net Value */
        var formulaRangeNetValue = ws.Range("AC6:AC" + lastRow); // Set the formula range from first cell to the last cell
        formulaRangeNetValue.FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-2]+RC[-1])-RC[-10]-RC[-9]"; //$" =IFERROR(O" + (Convert.ToInt32(lastDataRow) - 2) + "*" + hfInternalrate.Value + ",\"\")"; // Set the formula for the range

        /* Column Total - Development Effort */
        var TotalFormulaForDevEffort = ws.Range("Q4:Q4"); // Set the formula range from first cell to the last cell
        TotalFormulaForDevEffort.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,Q6:Q" + lastRow + ")";
        TotalFormulaForDevEffort.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0xDC4133);
        TotalFormulaForDevEffort.Style.Font.FontSize = 15;
        TotalFormulaForDevEffort.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        TotalFormulaForDevEffort.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.White;

        /* Column Total - Annual Maintenance Hrs */
        //var TotalAnnualMaintenanceHrs = ws.Range("R4:R4"); // Set the formula range from first cell to the last cell
        //TotalAnnualMaintenanceHrs.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R6:R" + lastRow + ")";
        //TotalAnnualMaintenanceHrs.Style.Font.FontSize = 15;
        //TotalAnnualMaintenanceHrs.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        //TotalAnnualMaintenanceHrs.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0x707070);

        /* Column Total - Development Cost */
        var TotalDevelopmentCost = ws.Range("S4:S4"); // Set the formula range from first cell to the last cell
        TotalDevelopmentCost.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,S6:S" + lastRow + ")";
        TotalDevelopmentCost.Style.Font.FontSize = 15;
        TotalDevelopmentCost.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        TotalDevelopmentCost.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0x707070);

        /* Column Total - Maintenance Cost */
        var TotalMaintenanceCost = ws.Range("T4:T4"); // Set the formula range from first cell to the last cell
        TotalMaintenanceCost.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,T6:T" + lastRow + ")";
        //TotalMaintenanceCost.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0xDC4133);
        TotalMaintenanceCost.Style.Font.FontSize = 15;
        TotalMaintenanceCost.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        TotalMaintenanceCost.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0x707070);

        /* Column Total - Monthly Target Users */
        var TotalMonthlyTargetUsers = ws.Range("U4:U4"); // Set the formula range from first cell to the last cell
        TotalMonthlyTargetUsers.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,U6:U" + lastRow + ")";
        TotalMonthlyTargetUsers.Style.Font.FontSize = 15;
        TotalMonthlyTargetUsers.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        TotalMonthlyTargetUsers.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0x707070);

        /* Column Total - Total Hrs Saved Per Year */
        var TotalHrsSavedPerYear = ws.Range("V4:V4"); // Set the formula range from first cell to the last cell
        TotalHrsSavedPerYear.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,V6:V" + lastRow + ")";
        TotalHrsSavedPerYear.Style.Font.FontSize = 15;
        TotalHrsSavedPerYear.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        TotalHrsSavedPerYear.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0x707070);

        /* Column Total - Soft Value */
        var TotalSoftValue = ws.Range("AA4:AA4"); // Set the formula range from first cell to the last cell
        TotalSoftValue.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,AA6:AA" + lastRow + ")";
        TotalSoftValue.Style.Font.FontSize = 15;
        TotalSoftValue.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        TotalSoftValue.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0x707070);

        /* Column Total - Hard Value */
        var TotalHardValue = ws.Range("AB4:AB4"); // Set the formula range from first cell to the last cell
        TotalHardValue.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,AB6:AB" + lastRow + ")";
        TotalHardValue.Style.Font.FontSize = 15;
        TotalHardValue.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        TotalHardValue.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0x707070);

        /* Column Total - Net Value */
        var TotalNetValue = ws.Range("AC4:AC4"); // Set the formula range from first cell to the last cell
        TotalNetValue.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,AC6:AC" + lastRow + ")";
        TotalNetValue.Style.Font.FontSize = 15;
        TotalNetValue.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        TotalNetValue.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0x707070);

        /* Development Cost & Maintenance Cost */
        var DevCostHeader = ws.Range("S5:S5"); var MainCostHeader = ws.Range("T5:T5");
        var NetValue = ws.Range("AC5:AC5"); var GoLive = ws.Range("AD5:AD5");

        DevCostHeader.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0xD0400C);
        DevCostHeader.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.White;
        MainCostHeader.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0xD0400C);
        MainCostHeader.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.White;

        NetValue.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0xD0400C);
        NetValue.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.White;
        GoLive.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0xD0400C);
        GoLive.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.White;

        /* Freeze First 2 Column */
        ws.SheetView.FreezeColumns(1); ws.SheetView.FreezeColumns(2);
        ws.Column("A").Hide();

        /* add internal & external rates */
        DataTable custTable = new DataTable("Customers");
        DataColumn dtColumn;
        DataRow myDataRow;

        // Create "irate" column
        dtColumn = new DataColumn();
        dtColumn.DataType = typeof(double);
        dtColumn.ColumnName = "irate";
        dtColumn.Caption = "irate";
        dtColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        dtColumn.Unique = true;
        // Add column to the DataColumnCollection.
        custTable.Columns.Add(dtColumn);

        // Create "erate" column
        dtColumn = new DataColumn();
        dtColumn.DataType = typeof(double);
        dtColumn.ColumnName = "erate";
        dtColumn.Caption = "erate";
        dtColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        dtColumn.Unique = true;
        // Add column to the DataColumnCollection.
        custTable.Columns.Add(dtColumn);

        // Add data rows to the custTable using NewRow method
        // I add three customers with their addresses, names and ids
        myDataRow = custTable.NewRow();
        myDataRow["irate"] = Convert.ToDouble(hfInternalrate.Value);
        myDataRow["erate"] = Convert.ToDouble(hfExternalrate.Value);
        custTable.Rows.Add(myDataRow);

        //Header cell
        var mergeRanges = ws.Range("C1:H1").Merge(); // Merge cell
        mergeRanges.SetValue("Rates mentioned below are used in the formula fields"); // Set merged cell value
        mergeRanges.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
        mergeRanges.Style.Font.Bold = true; // merged cell Bold
        mergeRanges.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0xFFFFFF); // Merged cell font color
        mergeRanges.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0x4A4A4A); // Merged cell BG color
        // Internal GSK Header
        var irateHeader = ws.Range("C2:E2").Merge(); // Internal Rate Header
        irateHeader.SetValue("Internal GSK Rate"); // Set cell value
        irateHeader.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
        irateHeader.Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
        irateHeader.Style.Font.Bold = false;
        irateHeader.Style.Border.TopBorder = XLBorderStyleValues.Thin;
        irateHeader.Style.Border.TopBorderColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0xFFFFFF);
        irateHeader.Style.Border.BottomBorder = XLBorderStyleValues.Thin;
        irateHeader.Style.Border.BottomBorderColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0xFFFFFF);
        irateHeader.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0xFFFFFF); // cell font color
        irateHeader.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0xF36633); // cell BG color
        // Internal GSK Rate
        var irate = ws.Range("F2:H2").Merge(); // Internal Rate
        irate.SetValue(Convert.ToDouble(custTable.Rows[0]["irate"].ToString())); // Set cell value
        irate.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
        irate.Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
        irate.Style.Font.FontSize = 26;
        irate.Style.Font.Bold = false;
        irate.Style.Border.BottomBorder = XLBorderStyleValues.Thin;
        irate.Style.Border.BottomBorderColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0xBFBFBF);
        //irateHeader.Style.Border.RightBorderColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0xBFBFBF);
        irate.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0xF36633); // cell font color
        //irate.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0x69B445); // cell BG color

        // External GSK Header
        var erateHeader = ws.Range("C3:E3").Merge(); // External Rate Header
        erateHeader.SetValue("External GSK Rate"); // Set cell value
        erateHeader.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
        erateHeader.Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
        erateHeader.Style.Font.Bold = false;
        erateHeader.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0xFFFFFF); // cell font color
        erateHeader.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0x6658A6);

        // External GSK Rate
        var erate = ws.Range("F3:H3").Merge(); // Internal Rate
        erate.SetValue(Convert.ToDouble(custTable.Rows[0]["erate"].ToString())); // Set cell value                    
        erate.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
        erate.Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
        erate.Style.Font.FontSize = 26;
        erate.Style.Font.Bold = false;
        erate.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.FromArgb(0x6658A6); // cell font color

        // Set Dropodwnlist for [Status] with values
        wb.Worksheet(6).Column(3).SetDataValidation().List(wsStatusMaster.Range("B2:B" + lastRowSM), true);
        // Set Dropodwnlist for [Phase] with values
        wb.Worksheet(6).Column(4).SetDataValidation().List(wsPhaseMaster.Range("B2:B" + lastRowPhaseMaster), true);
        // Set Dropodwnlist for [Product Life] with values
        wb.Worksheet(6).Column(5).SetDataValidation().List(wsProductLifeMaster.Range("B2:B" + lastRowProductLifeMaster), true);
        // Set Dropodwnlist for [WREF BU] with values
        wb.Worksheet(6).Column(6).SetDataValidation().List(wsWREFBUMaster.Range("B2:B" + lastRowWREFBUMaster), true);
        // Set Dropodwnlist for [Kai Service Line] with values
        

        //var sourcecellrange = wsKAIServiceLineMaster.Range("B2:B" + lastRowWREFBUMaster);
        //var cellrangetoactivate = wb.Worksheet(6).Range("L6:L" + lastRow);
        //cellrangetoactivate.DataType = XLDataType.Text;
        //var values = cellrangetoactivate.Cells().First().Value.ToString().Split(',');
        //var formula = $"COUNTIF(A1,\"*\"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(\"{string.Join(",", values)}\",\",\",\"|\"),\" \",\"*\"))=COUNTIF(A1,\"*\")";
        //cellrangetoactivate.SetDataValidation().Custom(formula);

        //wb.Worksheet(6).Column(7).SetDataValidation().List(wsKAIServiceLineMaster.Range("B2:B" + lastRowWREFBUMaster), true);

        wsStatusMaster.Hide(); // hide status master sheet
        wsPhaseMaster.Hide(); // hide phase master sheet
        wsProductLifeMaster.Hide(); // hide product life master sheet
        wsWREFBUMaster.Hide(); // hide WREF BU master sheet

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment;filename=KAISummaryReportExport_" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + ".xlsx");
        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```